# Can/how do i add a spinner animation during the ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, kaminari

I am very new to jquery and trying to figure out if I am able to add a spinner to use in conjunction with Kaminari

I have pagination of 200 Contacts with code below.

```
<%= paginate contacts, remote: true, params: { :controller => "contacts", :action => "index" } %>`
```

I can see that I need to use some code like this:

```
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $loading.hide();
  });
```

my question is where do put this?
- at the bottom of the the page
- in a js.erb
- somewhere else?

what do i need to do to get it to trigger with Kaminari?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a wrapper `div` for your loading spinner.

```
<div class="loadingDiv">your_loading_spinner</div>
```

At top of your page;

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

And at the end of your page;

```
<script>
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
 })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $loading.hide();
});
</script>
```

You can find some loading spinners from [loading.io](http://loading.io/).

Comment: how does it associate itself with the Kaminari line of code?

Comment: If you can edit your question and show me the Kaminari line of code, I can help with that too.